# creating an array in jsp from list of objects

Tags: javascript, jsp, jstl

I am trying to build an array of DemoNames.name attribute, dynamically in jsp, how can i create an array and then pass to my js file for further validation?

```
<c:forEach items="${demoNames}" var="DemoNames">
  ${DemoNames.name}
</c:forEach>
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to make this code declaration somewhere in the html after the js file is declared.

```
<script>
  var nameArray = [];
  <c:forEach items="${demoNames}" var="DemoNames">
    nameArray.push("${DemoNames.name}");
  </c:forEach>
  yourJSFileFunction( nameArray );
</script>
```

If you viewed source on this I believe you would have a push line for each of the names.